# Tracking Optimize anti-flicker snippet timeout using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

How to successfully detect and track Optimize anti-flicker snippet timeout using Google Analytics?

I noticed that the `dataLayer` variable `hide["GTM-XXXXXX"]` is `true` when it times out and `false` if it doesn't.

The problem is that there is no event tied to this variable change. How would you go about tracking timeouts?

My goal is to send an event to Google Analytics every time the snippet times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up with. Works perfectly.

**1. Create a new Custom Javascript function variable in GTM**

```
function () { 
    if ( window.dataLayer.hide ) { 
        return window.dataLayer.hide["GTM-xxxxxxx"]; // Your Optimize container ID
    } 
}
```

**2. On DOM Ready, check its value**

If the value is `true`, the snippet has timed out. And when it's `false`, it managed to run before your maximum timeout duration.

[A more detailed tutorial can be found here.](https://reflectivedata.com/tracking-optimize-anti-flicker-snippet-timeout-in-google-analytics/)

Comment: Hi, I get "(not set)" values instead of "false". Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this solution in practice, but you might want to give it a try.

If you look at the [developer guide of Google Optimize](https://developers.google.com/optimize/), you can find a very detailed explanation of the functionality of the anti-flicker code (page hiding snippet). The relevant code and comment is the following:

```
// Creates a timeout that will call the page-showing function after the
// timeout amount (defaulting to 4 seconds), in the event that Optimize has
// not already loaded. This ensures your page will not stay hidden in the
// event that Optimize takes too long to load.
  setTimeout(function() {
    i();
    h.end = null
  }, c);
  h.timeout = c;
```

In this timeout `i()` is responsible for removing the class, that hides the page by default.

So theoretically, you could alter this part of the code, and bind the event tracking to it, by generating a GTM event, via the `dataLayer`. E.g.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  i();
  h.end = null;

  //added code: notify Google Tag Manager about the timeout
  dataLayer.push({
    event: 'trackAntiFlickerTimeout'
  });

}, c);
```

Obviously, you need to use this event as a trigger, and make the necessary event tag to fire, and send data to Google Analytics.